# ffmpeg supply key to override m3u8 encryption key

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, aes, command-line-arguments, m3u8

I want to convert some m3u8 to mp4 but the way they supply the `EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI=` in the m3u8 it doesn't directly point to the key. I can get the key just fine through a different endpoint. But is there a way to tell ffmpeg to "use this key instead" when its decrypting all the `.ts` files?

Comment: Hi Michael, did you manage to find the answer? I have the same problem right now.

Comment: @Heisenbug, I did not. I downloaded every .ts file and decrypted them myself, then removed the EXT-X-KEY line and then converted it with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

i use 1dm download manager in android (i don't know alternatives in pc) to download the m3u8 files. it then asks for key just enter it that's it.